# php mysql on mint 12?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2, linuxmint

I am trying to install PHP MySQL on Mint 12. I downloaded and installed [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html). According to the tutorial, when I go to `localhost` in a browser I should see [this](http://www.apachefriends.org/images/380.jpg):

Instead, I see:

```
It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

I realize this is the Apache success page, but why am I seeing it instead of the XAMPP page? How do I fix it? Where should PHP source files be stored on Mint?

**EDIT** PLEASE read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/359318/mint-12-i-cant-remove-apache)

Comment: I have xampp installed on xp, i'll be happy if you at least help me get mysql working! and i don't really care about phpmyadmin, i can use  sqlbuddy

Comment: Did you access the `index.php` ? The apache default page is `index.html`.

Comment: @xdazz from where? i don't really know where the files are located, i'm new to mint

Comment: What is in your address bar?

Comment: @xdazz `localhost` and `localhost/index.html` display `it works` and `localhost/index.php` displays `file not found, 404 error`

Comment: what about `localhost/xampp/index.php`?

Comment: @xdazz `localhost/xampp/index.php` displays `404 error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly downloading and installing XAMPP, I would suggest you to use Mint/Ubuntu's built in repositories to install: MySQL, Apache, PHP...

Comment: from the software manager? I tried that but can't access www/var so i uninstalled them and installed xampp